# GitLab CI/CD Pipeline Fails with 'Host Unknown' Error when Deploying Configurations to Local Network Devices

Tags: networking, gitlab, continuous-integration, devops

I'm currently facing an issue with my GitLab CI/CD pipeline, and I could use some assistance. Here's the problem:

I have a network setup in GNS3 where I'm simulating multiple network devices, each with its own IP address. I've written an Ansible playbook that successfully pushes configurations from a text file to these network devices when executed on my local machine. I can confirm that I can access the devices using SSH on my local machine.

However, when I try to deploy the configurations using the same playbook within the GitLab CI environment, the pipeline consistently fails with an error message stating "host unknown."

To resolve this issue, I've already made some modifications to the GitLab Runner Docker and shell configurations. I set the network_mode to "host" and made similar changes, hoping that it would allow the pipeline to successfully communicate with the network devices. Unfortunately, the problem persists.

I suspect that the pipeline environment is unable to resolve the hostnames/IP addresses of the local network devices in my my local machine It's worth noting that I'm able to SSH into these devices from my local machine, but the GitLab CI environment seems to have trouble establishing the connection.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before?

[playbook execution in job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6DVe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try and add a `ssh-keyscan 172.100.100.2 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` step to your GitLab CI/CD job executed in your GitLab runner.

SSH will need that in order to not trip up at the "authenticity of host" step.
It might work in your normal environment (because your own `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is already configured), but it won't work in a GitLab runner docker container, with its own filesytem.